# ¿Cómo añado el área bajo la curva en ggroc?

Tags: r

Hola gente buenas noches, estoy intentando hacer una curva roc con el paquete pROC. Mi problema es que quiero graficarla con ggroc que es una funcion de la misma librería, el problema es que no sé como obtener los mismos resultados que logro al utilizar la función plot de r base, por ejemplo quiero obtener ese intersecto que se muestra en la imagen, que es el mejor punto de corte pero con ggroc. ¿Alguien que haya utilizado este paquete que me pueda ayudar?

Adjunto el plot1 y plot2, el primero con la función plot de r y el segundo con ggroc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Has visto los ejemplos de la ayuda de `ggroc` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pROC/versions/1.16.2/topics/ggroc.roc? son bastante claros, la intersección la puedes dibujar con un `geom_segment`. Por que no intentas plantear un ejemplo mínimo con el código de lo que has intentando y sobre eso vemos de ayudarte?